# Converting from UNIX time to .NET DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() (in python)

Tags: python, .net, unix-timestamp

CLARIFICATION: I am asking if anything is wrong with my method, or if there is a less clumsy way to do it.

I have two sets of UTC timestamps in log files that I need to establish a correspondence between. One uses a YYYY:MM:DD hh:mm:ss:ms format, and another uses the Int64 returned from .NET's DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc(). I set out to convert the full date format to the Int64 format in Python.

.NET's DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx

Finding the correct solution to this was a confusing hunt. Unfortunately, I found out that python and .NET seem to use different epochs, starting in 1970 and 1601 respectively.

Python's calendar.timegm(), which I use to get a quantity in seconds:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm

Here's the code I'm using. It appears to work properly. I hope it is useful to more than just myself.

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar


NET_epoch = datetime(1601,1,1)
UNIX_epoch = datetime(1970,1,1)

epoch_delta = (UNIX_epoch - NET_epoch)

#example time in September, 2012
year = 2012
month = 9
day = 9
hour = 23
minute = 56
second = 22
millisecond = 12

#Thankfully I'm not worrying about timezones

log_time = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second) #,millisecond)
# millisecond not included since its precision is not used at the moment.

unix_ts = calendar.timegm(log_time.timetuple())
#units of seconds since UNIX epoch

net_ts = calendar.timegm( (log_time + epoch_delta).timetuple() )
#units of seconds since NET epoch

net_filetime_ts = net_ts* (10**7) + millisecond * (10**4)
#units of 100 ns since NET epoch
#corresponds to .NET DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: No, more so "Am I doing anything wrong here, or is there a more elegant way do to this? If not, I hope this is useful to someone else, as it took a while to figure out."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's more helpful and simpler to get the time relative to the UNIX epoch in C#? I believe it should look like this:

```
(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime (1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Since 2015, one can also use `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`. It is a 64-bit integer, not a `double` floating point.